# Nginx: Is it possible to resolve to different services based on a regexp over the URL and method?

Tags: regex, nginx, server

I searched and I couldnt' find any way to do this, so I am wondering if it is possible.

I have a service running that accepts requests and everything works fine. However, I'd like to answer some of these requests with a different service running on the same machine. These requests are the ones going to `some/path/{variable}/etc` and method `POST`.

So I would like to know if it possible to do this directly from nginx without adding any overhead.

My first solution was creating a different API that receives all the requests and if it is not the one I want to incercept, just did a proxy request to the origianl service. But this added between 200 and 500ms to every response, which is not acceptable in our use case.

So I thought that doing this through nginx would resolve much faster, but I couldn't find a way or even find out if it is possible.

Any help would be highly appreciated. If you have any other idea or alternative that I could test or implement, it would be welcome as well.

Edit: Per request by Ivan's comment.

We have already nginx running, serving all the requests by service1.

What we would like to do is:

```
if request.path is in the form of /path/{variable}/etc and request.method==POST:
      serve using service2
else:
      serve using service1
```

Comment: It is possible, but you need to add more information to your question. What are exact rules to distinguish two types of the requests? Do you already have an nginx instance or just planning to add it to your server?

Comment: Hello @IvanShatsky, I edited the post with an example of the logic we are trying to achieve. We have nginx running.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your current nginx config to your question too.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that in case of the `GET` request it should be sent to the first service even if its URI matches the `/path/{variable}/etc` pattern? Any limits what that `{variable}` can be?

Comment: ```{variable}``` is a alphanumeric string, and yes, if it is a ```GET```it should go to ```service1``` (the ```else``` in the example). I don't have access to the nginx config right now but I will in a few hours.

Comment: Posted some kind of a preliminary answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you services hosted on the same server and differs in access ports, using a chain of the [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks should do the trick:

```
map $uri $service_by_uri {
    ~^/path/[\w]+/etc    127.0.0.1:10002; # service 2
    default              127.0.0.1:10001; # service 1
}
map $request_method $service {
    POST                 $service_by_uri; # select service according to the request URI
    default              127.0.0.1:10001; # service 1
}
server {
    ...
    proxy_pass           http://$service;
    ...
}
```